# Картинка в ссылке

Tags: php, joomla, cms

Стоит такая задачка на Joomla сделать так чтоб при отправке статьи или какой другой либо ссылке ведущей на нужный мне сайт в скайпе появлялась картинка которая мне нужна. Как вообще генерируется картинка в ссылке? Даже не могу правильно сформулировать вопрос в гугле чтоб получить нужный мне ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте opengraph http://ogp.me/

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Site Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://my.site.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://my.site.com/images/thumb.png" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Site description" />
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. А прописывать их где? В самом шаблоне?

Comment: Поищите готовый плагин для этого, потому как на каждой странице в этих тегах должно быть свое значение, в шаблоне такое не сделаеш

Comment: Я никогда не работал с джумлой, но думаю там есть какой нибудь для социальных сетей и сео с поддержкой opengraph

Comment: Спасибо. Решил вопрос сделал свое решение без плагина.